# android ViewPager customizable

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to implement a scroll view as shown:

[image]

That is, in "idle" state image "1" is visible in full size and image "2" is visible partially (thus giving a clue to the user that he can scroll the content). After scrolling scrool view must not stay in intermediate state and scrolling must be completed (like iOS's Scroll View does when "Paging Enabled" is turned on):

[image]

I refused to use `HorizontalScrollView`, because it has nothing similar to "Paging Enabled" property.

After googling, I came across `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. It's scrolling behavior is perfectly what I want, but I have no good idea how to support "partially visible" next image in `ViewPager`? Technically, what should I return in the

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)?
```

For the present, my code is

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stage_select_image_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.stage_select_image_layout_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(m_imageResourceId);
    return view;
}
```

But it results in "exactly one image per page" behavior, not what I want (see the very first figure).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
    ViewPager pager = ...;
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    pager.setPageMargin(-200);
```

Comment: Are you able to see the left side view by this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is, is in your PagerAdapter, implement an override for getPageWidth.  The return value is a percent that the view takes up of the total space.

```
@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    return 0.75f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [widthFactor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.LayoutParams.html#widthFactor) attribute of the ViewPager's LayoutParams. It should scale it so you can see a little of the next page.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `widthFactor` directly, instead you should return the desired value in your PagerAdapter's `getPageWidth()` implementation.