# How to use setOffscreenPageLimit in UIScrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to implement ViewPager functionality in iOS. For example, scrollview is having 10 images. When the user is on his current page, we need to show some extent of either side of pages.

Like In android, View Pager is having a method like, setOffscreenPageLimit. It did the same usage.
 This is example in android

[android ViewPager customizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050720/android-viewpager-customizable)

How can I implement the same functionality in iOS.

Please suggest me.

Comment: http://code4app.net/ios/View-Pager/4fe7e7d96803fa6b2c000000

Comment: How about you use UIPageViewController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html ?

Comment: Thanks for reply Abbie. I am not looking for images with scrollview. I need to show the current image as idle and either side of images partially.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with the help of following link.

http://cases.azoft.com/creating-image-gallery-ios-apps-uiimageview/

Hope this link is useful for others.